# Geometry of complex numbers in specific set

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Given the complex number $\alpha=3-4i$ and the complex set
>
> $$S=\{z\in\mathbb{C} | |z|=5\}$$
>
> Show that $\alpha\in S$. Illustrate it.

---

I know the length of $\alpha$ is 5, but I'm not sure how to illustrate this graphically. Is it supposed to be a circle with a radius of 5?

Comment: Yes. But graphing is not an accurate or a reliable method of proving anything in complex analysis. You should rather show arithmetically that $\alpha$ satisfies the defining condition of the set $S$, namely that $|\alpha| = 5$.

Comment: I know how to do it arithmetically, it's the graphing part I'm not sure about.

Comment: OK, $|z|$ is the distance of the point $z$ – a graphical representation of the number $z$ on a complex plane – from the point $(0,0)$. So: YES, your set $S$ is a set of all points $5$ units apart from the origin, that is a circle of radius $5$. And $\alpha$ is a point $3$ units along the real axis and $-4$ units by the imaginary axis. Which happens to lie on the circle. (But _that_ needs to be shown by calculation, not by drawing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution to the "Illustrate it" part of your problem:

[image: Expertly drawn in Paint]

Were I correcting this submission as a teacher, I would point out that the names $\alpha$ and $S$ are missing, and probably something about handwriting in Paint not being a good idea.

Comment: And that's it rather $5i$ on the top and $-5i$ on the bottom of the circle.

Comment: @Berci Well, that's true, although as markers on a grid, $5$ is not directly wrong.